# C++ Inheritance Rules for Subscript Operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword, subscript

I have a question regarding the subscript operator, overloading, and inheritance in C++. <strike>I'm pretty sure that if you have a parent class with multiple function overloads, it is possible for the child to override just one of the functions and inherit the rest. The same does not seem to apply to the subscript operator.</strike> (I made a bad assumption. It is really no different than any other function.)  Consider the following code:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

struct Parent
{
   virtual ~Parent() {}
   virtual int operator[](A index) { return -1; }
   virtual int operator[](B index) { return -2; }
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
   virtual int operator[](B index) override { return -3; }
};

int main()
{
   // error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Child' and 'A')
   return Child()[A()]; 
}
```

I would expect for it to use the subscript operator from the parent instead of causing an error. Is it possible to inherit some overloaded subscript operators from the parent and override others? If not, is there any better solution than doing:

```
struct Child : public Parent
{
    virtual int operator[](B index) override { return -3; }
    // Force it to use the parent method
    virtual int operator[](A index) override { return Parent::operator[](index); }
};
```

Since I potentially inherit from the parent many places, and it is bad for maintenance to have to manually specify functions like this. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: There's always `using Parent::operator[]` but you still have to write it in each class.

Comment: Overload resolution stops as soon as it finds any candidates with the desired name.  So it will see `Child::operator[](B)` and stop looking for additional overloads, so it never sees a version that takes an `A`.  If you do `using Parent::operator[]` like @JamesRoot suggests, it will bring all additional overloads into the scope of `Child` so overloads will work as you expect.

Comment: What gives you the idea that this problem is different just because it's the subscript operator? Modify your code to use an ordinary function called `f` and you'll encounter the same compilation error.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, yes. I made an incorrect assumption. It is a C++ limitation for all functions.

Comment: @JamesRoot (and @0x5453), I like that idea. I will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid two things in C++:

- Mixing overloading and overriding.
- Public virtual functions (if it's not the destructor).

Keep your base-class overloaded operators non-virtual and have them delegate to private virtual functions with distinct names.

Here is an example:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

struct Parent
{
   virtual ~Parent() {}
   int operator[](A index) { return withA(index); }
   int operator[](B index) { return withB(index); }
private:
   virtual int withA(A index) { return -1; }
   virtual int withB(B index) { return -2; }
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
private:
   virtual int withB(B index) override { return -3; }
};

int main()
{
   return Child()[A()]; 
}
```

This approach, also known as the [Non-Virtual Interface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm), represents a nice separation of concerns between the clients of the base class and the implementors of derived classes. It also solves your compilation problem as a side effect.

Comment: I left the virtual destructor off to simplify the example, but yes, technically it should be there (I added it to the question).  This is a valid idea, but I will go with James Root's idea.  Thanks.